# iOS (iPad) CoreGraphics & Foundation memory issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management, instruments

I'm getting strange memory allocations from core iOS libraries, seen in Instruments Allocations (Malloc 1.00KB) which continually rise and result in app crash (iPad).

The app allows the user to browse through articles (body in webview, title/author/date in labels) - the problem occurring as each new view controller is loaded (previous view controllers are released/deallocating - this isn't the problem).

The following CoreGraphics allocations only happen when the .text property is set for the UILabel:
CoreGraphics "**CGGLyphBitmapCreate**", "**CGFontSetStrikeValue**" - sometimes one or both of these shows 6 or 7 times (1KB each) but at least one of each every time view loads.

In addition to this, Foundation "**[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]**" sometimes appears, sometimes not, sometimes up to 6/7 times on one load. I understand why adding observes this might allocate some memory, but surely deallocating view controller with "**[NSNotificationCenter removeObserver:self]** should remove all references again.

I've included screenshots from Instruments... won't even address the WebCore and libcache.dylib allocations that **sometimes show up on load. Very confused here too.

[image: Instruments Screenshot 1]
[image: Instruments Screenshot 2]

Comment: Okay - I've debugged further and it seems like the "CGGLyphBitmapCreate" lines only appear while I use 'Georgia' font as opposed to the default 'Helvetica'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you track leaks? As long as it doesn't leak memory you normally don't have to worry.

Comment: Tracking leaks using Instruments, shows no noticeable memory leaks (only 3 related to coredata, resulting in just over 100bytes).

- but this "Malloc 1.00KB" keeps building up the more I browse, finally resulting in memory warning 1, then 2 and crash.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a thread without an autorelease pool set up? If this is the case, and an autorelease object is created, e.g. by a getter method, the object cannot be retained by an autorelease pool since it does not exist, and it will leak.
So it your app is multithreaded, make sure that every thread has an `@autoreleasepool{}` block that covers most of the thread code.